# Ubuntu 16.04: No sound

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My laptop is dualbooted, the sound is great in windows 10, however, in ubuntu 16.04 there's no sound, everything was great, yesterday, it just disappeared

`sudo apt-get install alsamixer   ## gives no package called alsamixer`

`sudo apt-get remove alsamixer   ## gives no package called alsamixer installed`

Pulse audio configuration tab gives

`no card available for configuration`

That's why I mentioned windows 10, just to say that my card is working. I don't want to upgrade to newer versions of ubuntu, I have software I cannot afford to lose or reinstall.

Even the wired headphones aren't working on ubuntu, my wireless speaker is working though.

Comment: @FloT I see `E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
`

Comment: Although I tried to kill it and start it again